# Two nested angular apps and constants

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a main app:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['secondApp'])
    .constant('config', {
        key: "mainKey"
    });
```

And the second app looks like this:

```
var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', [])
    .constant('config', {
        key: "secondKey"
    });
```

When I am injecting `config` into a directive in the second app:

```
secondApp.directive("ngTest", function (config) {
});
```

config is being initialized from the main app config. What I am doing wrong here? When I name a constant differently and injecting with the different name it works fine.

```
var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', [])
    .constant('secondConfig', {
        key: "secondKey"
    });

secondApp.directive("ngTest", function (secondConfig) {
});
```

Version is: `AngularJS v1.5.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJs 1 not does not handle namespace collisions.

So if you are using two module in one APP having same named

> 1. Services
> 2. Factory
> 3. Constants

So according to me best to overcome this problem is:

Just give some prefix to your variable 
Like::

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['secondApp'])
    .constant('mainApp_config', {
        key: "mainKey"
    });


var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', [])
    .constant('secondApp_config', {
        key: "secondKey"
    });
```

I know this is not a solution which may you are looking...
this is only way I know i can suggest to you.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how to search this issue. Once you named it a `namespace collision` I know read about it and this seems the only way.